# Probability Game

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A game has the following rule -

*“Scissors cuts paper. Paper covers rock. Rock crushes lizard. Lizard poisons Spock. Spock smashes scissors. Scissors decapitates lizard. Lizard eats paper. Paper disproves Spock. Spock vaporizes rock. And as it always has, rock crushes scissors”.*

**Determine the probability that friend A beats friend B in this game.** We know the probabilities that any of the friends choose any object in the game. Also we know that they play till two wins, so **the winner of the game is the person who first wins two rounds.**

Let AR, ASc, AP, AL, ASp – the probabilities that friend A chooses rock, scissors, paper, lizard or Spock respectively. Let BR, BSc, BP, BL, BSp – the probabilities that friend B chooses rock, scissors, paper, lizard or Spock respectively.

0 <= AR, ASc, AP, AL, ASp <= 1

AR + ASc + AP + AL + ASp = 1

0 <= BR, BSc, BP, BL, BSp <= 1

BR + BSc + BP + BL + BSp = 1

*Note : I approached using conditional probability and also Bayes Theorem.Both failed. Am I doing something wrong ?*

Comment: A Big Bang Theory reference...

Comment: It's actually a game in real world.BBT never created the game.Yes,the words are from BBT.

Comment: Based on the show, $Asp=Bsp=1$

Comment: @Jean > LOL ! But please help me here someone !

Answer (score 0):

Unless the probabilities change with time, it's enough to find the probability that a person wins a single round.  I assume in the case of a tie the round is replayed, so $A$ wins with probability $p$, $B$ wins with probability $q$ and $p+q<1$ (because of ties).  If the round is replayed until someone wins, $A$ will be that winner with probability $\frac{p}{p+q}$.  Playing this twice, $A$ will be the winner with probability $\left(\frac{p}{p+q}\right)^2$.

Comment: Let AR, ASc, AP, AL, ASp and BR, BSc, BP, BL, BSp be .10, .20, .30, .40, 0 and .10, .10, .10, .10, .60 respectively.Then is this the answer : 
p = [ .1*(.1+.1) + .2*(.1+.1) + .3*(.1+.6) + .4*(.1+.6) ]
and q = [ .1*(.1+.6) + .2*(.1+.6) + .3*(.1+.1) + .4*(.1+.1) ]

Comment: Some one please help !

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested computation for $p$ looks correct but your computation of $q$ is not correct.

The probability that B wins by playing Scissors is $0.1\cdot(0.3+0.4)$ for example. List all the other possibilities and do the sum.

Note that vadim123 has then given you the formula for A winning two times in a row which is not needed for him to win.

Comment: I calculated the probability of A losing the game in  _q = [ .1*(.1+.6) + .2*(.1+.6) + .3*(.1+.1) + .4*(.1+.1) ]_ which is correct according to logic. Then the tie probability stands to be 1-p-q=.1 (as p=.55 and q=.35)

Comment: valid games the first player wins:
12TTT1,
T2TT1TTT1,
TTTTT11

These sequences are valid with the second player winning:
TT22,
T1T2TT2,
122,

This sequences are invalid:
112TT,
1TT1TT

Comment: By calculation prob. of 1st player winning is : 0.079 and that of second player winning is : 0.021. Is this correct ? Everything is totally based on this !

Comment: Ah, I understand your calculation of q now. It looks correct. You can ignore ties in the second step of your calculation if you use $c =\frac p {p+q}$ as the winning chance for A. Then the probability of player A winning at least two games out of three is $c^3+3c^2(1-c)$.